# Looking for search engine keyword that names the following problem (or solution)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms

For a given finite set of elements S, find all combinations of non-overlapping subsets such that the union of all subsets in a combination equals the set S. For example for S = {1, 2, 3},
$$\text{combinations} = \{(1, 2, 3)\}, \{(1), (2), (3)\}, \{(1, 2), (3)\}, \{(1, 3), (2)\}, \{(2, 3), (1)\}$$

What is the name of such a problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

Comment: You want the number of ways to partition the set.

Comment: Thank you, just couldn't think of the word partitioning somehow!